# GLSL shader read buffer (pointers)?

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, glsl

Didn't really know what to call the title, but im looking at some example code:

```
try
        {
            // Open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // Read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // Convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        //Convert converted strings into c strings
        const GLchar* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const GLchar * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
    // 2. Compile shaders
    GLuint vertex, fragment;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    // Vertex Shader
    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
```

it's reading shader files from another file (this is in a class). It reads them in as a string...makes sense, and then converts them into c strings(i presume) to then create and compile the shader.

I guess my confusion is, were taking a stream and converting them into a string variable (vertexCode and fragmentCode). And then we call .c_str() (which I presume converted them into a c string) and storing them in a pointer called vShaderCode and fShaderCode.

Wouldn't the pointer be pointing to the the c_string itself? Im still not 100% on pointers in general...but shouldn't the GLchar* vShaderCode be equal to the address of something?

Then we go down and refer to &vShaderCode so were referring to the address of the pointer....

Im getting really confused at whats going on here. Im still not 100% with pointers so following the "memory map" of whats going on is confusing.

Full class example here if needed:
http://www.learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?type=header&code=shader

Comment: read the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glShaderSource.xhtml) first: you pass a pointer to several strings, that's what the `1` is for: there's only one string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the function `glShaderSource` is to read GLSL source code. Now how can we represent plaintext source code in C? Well, a single line of source code can be represented by `char*`. Then multiple lines of source code can be represented by an array of those `char*`'s, in other words with `char**`.

So view the `const GLchar**` as an array of strings, representing plaintext source code.

Now, only knowing `char**` is not enough, we need to know the number of lines in the source code too, i.e. the size of the array of `char*`'s. That's what the second argument of `glShaderSource` is for. You specify the number of `char*`'s with it. In your example, it is `1`, because the shader source code is "flattened" to a single line (not a good idea if you have some `#define` or `#version` somewhere in your GLSL code).

That solves the problem of how many lines of code there are, but then there's the problem of knowing how long each line of code is. That's what the fourth argument of `glShaderSource` is for. It is an array of integers, specifying how long each line of source code is. In other words, it's yet again an array, that is `int*`. We know how long this array is, because that's exactly the second argument of `glShaderSource`.

When every line of source code ends with a null terminator (`\0`), there's no need to specify how long each line of source code is. In this case, it's possible to specify `NULL` as the fourth argument of `glShaderSource`. OpenGL then assumes that every source code line is null terminated.

Comment: Why does the source code just contain const GLchar* instead of **? is it just because we have one string im assuming?

Comment: Yes, since the source code is "flattened" to a single line, we can make do with `char*` instead. To make it into a `char**`, you take the `&`.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by you take the `&`

Comment: By "take the `&`" I mean that you reference the object. You get a pointer to that object.